# How to pass some taken value in a view and then send it to another view in laravel?

Tags: laravel-5

I have a table called pages then in one of my views I used this table as:

```
@foreach ($pages as $page)
            @if ($subject->names == $page->related_subject)
              <li><a href="{{route('showPage')}}"><i class="fa fa-circle-o">
              </i><span> {{$page->title}}</span></a>
             </a></li>
            @endif
@endforeach
```

in my loop I put a link to another view and I want to send the record to that view with this link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `$page` is an Eloquent `Model`, you're looking for [Route Model Binding](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing#route-model-binding).

You can pass your `Model` to the route like this:
`route('showPage', ['page' => $page])`

And then simply type-hint it in your `Controller` method:
`public function show(Page $page)`.

Make sure your Route is also set up to expect the page parameter:
`Route::get('/page/show/{page}, ...)`

Comment: can you explain more about this: Route::get('/show_page/{page}',[
  'uses' => '\Schools\Http\Controllers\AdminController@indexShow',
  'as' => 'showPage',
]);because when I add it my template will be mess up.

Comment: What exactly is messed up? Are you getting some kind of error?

Comment: No I don't have error but I'm using a bootstrap template and now it is mess up.